# Unable to figure out cause of Invalid Hook call react error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, react-dom

Hi I'm building a react application and get the invalid hook call error. I've found a few posts about this error here and on other pages but none of them has helped me understand what's wrong in this case.

This is the error message

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. >This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching >versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the >Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See >https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this >problem.

```
15 | if (res.ok) {
16 | setSigned_in(true); res.json().then(r => {setRole(r.role); setProfile(r);}).catch(err => alert(err));
17 | } else {
18 | setSigned_in(false); (error comes from this lien!??)
| ^ 19 | setRole(null);
20 | }
21 | })()
```

It's caused by a hook call from inside a custom hook

```
export const useLogin = () => {
    const [signed_in, setSigned_in] = useState(null);
    const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const res = await fetch('/api/profile/', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') } });
            if (res.ok) {
                setSigned_in(true); res.json().then(r => {setRole(r.role); setProfile(r);}).catch(err => alert(err));
            } else {
                setSigned_in(false);
                setRole(null);
            }
        })()
    }, dependents);

    return {
        signed_in,
        setSigned_in,
        role,
        profile,
        setRole,
        setProfile
    }
```

As far as I understand this should be a valid hook call right? So it should be caused by double copies of react or mismatching versions of react and react-dom?? However I don't understand how to find out if that's the case. Running npm ls yields

```
├── @emotion/react@11.4.0
├── @emotion/styled@11.3.0
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.35
├── @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.15.3
├── @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.14
├── @material-ui/core@5.0.0-beta.0
├── @material-ui/icons@5.0.0-beta.1
├── @material-ui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.39
├── @material-ui/styles@5.0.0-beta.1
├── @react-google-maps/api@2.2.0
├── @use-gesture/react@10.1.4
├── bindings@1.5.0 extraneous
├── bootstrap@5.0.2
├── chokidar@3.5.2
├── cra-append-sw@2.7.0
├── file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 extraneous
├── mdbreact@5.1.0
├── nan@2.14.2 extraneous
├── node-geocoder@3.27.0
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-router-dom@5.2.0
├── react-scripts@4.0.2
├── react-spring@9.3.0
├── react@17.0.2
└── reactstrap@8.9.0
```

I can only see one react and react and react-dom are both version 17.0.2.

Does anyone know a good way to fix this issue and possibly explain how to avoid getting it again (it has appeared multiple times before and previously vanished without explanation)

Comment: where are you using this hook ?

Comment: Can you provide details about `dependents`? `useEffect` dependencies are supposed to be an array containing the values that you want this hook to "watch" in future renders. I can't think of any other problem with your code besides that.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this on a clean react app and see
and one more thing dependents not defined

Comment: Yes the hook seems to work fine.

The dependents constant wasn't undefined the code was actually like this
`useLogin = (dependents) =>{
       dependents = dependents || []
       //rest of code
`
I removed that parameter now anyways because it was never used and replaced it with an empty list as suggested. However I still get the same error. Havn't run it on a smaller app yet but this hook worked for before...

I'm starting to think it might be caused by mismatching version of react-router-dom as found [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7695) v5.2 with react17.

Comment: check node_modules/react-router/package.json

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a red herring. For your effect hook, the dependencies should be `[]` instead of `dependents` (which is likely `undefined`). (There's also a missing curly brace at the end of the function.)

Does this fix it?

```js
export const useLogin = () => {
    const [signed_in, setSigned_in] = useState(null);
    const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const res = await fetch('/api/profile/', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') } });
            if (res.ok) {
                setSigned_in(true); res.json().then(r => {setRole(r.role); setProfile(r);}).catch(err => alert(err));
            } else {
                setSigned_in(false);
                setRole(null);
            }
        })()
    }, []);

    return {
        signed_in,
        setSigned_in,
        role,
        profile,
        setRole,
        setProfile
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answers guys. I think it was caused by some mismatch between reaact-router-dom and react. Updating react-router-dom to latest version and migrating to yarn instead of npm seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: This could be posted as a comment instead of an answer.